# TYPO3 News Embeded youtube video with related link in fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid

I use TYPO3 news related link to embed a Youtube video.

In fluid I have use this code:

f:format.htmlspecialchars()} src="{relatedLink.uri}" width="480">

The result is: `<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="270" title="Test video title src=" https:="" www.youtube.com="" embed="" 0ofotivopuo?ecver="1&quot;" width="480"></iframe>`

You can see that src have a link with no slashes.
When i debug the same variable {relatedLink.uri} in a

tag i get the right url like this : https://www.youtube.com/embed/0oFotIvOpUo?ecver=1

Can anybody give an idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Try <f:debug>{relatedLink}</f:debug> to see what is in. I think there are many different content types which can com from EXT:news related. You can iterate over them. See http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-project-tt-news/2013-January/003663.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing quote after `title="{relatedLink.title -> f:format.htmlspecialchars()}` is probably the reason for your problem.

Fixed version:

```html
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="270"  title="{relatedLink.title -> f:format.htmlspecialchars()}" src="{relatedLink.uri}" width="480"></iframe>
```